# django views - hyperlinks with thumbnails

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm brand new to django front-end web development.

I have an `index.html` in my templates folder which has two thumbnails for sign up or login, and clicking on them directs you to `signup.html` and `login.html`. I have included the respective urls for those in `urls.py`. I'm stuck as to how I can edit my `views.py` so that I can record which option the user takes in order to perform the directing. I've used hyperlinks and thumbnails in my HTML code.

Currently my `views.py` looks like this:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from .models import Customer

 # Create your views here.
 def index(request):
    return render(request, 'newuser/index.html', {})

 def login(request):
    return render(request, 'newuser/login.html', {})

def signup(request):
    return render(request, 'newuser/signup.html', {})`
```

And `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^login$', views.login, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^signup$', views.signup, name = 'signup'),
]
```

And finally, this is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Zucumber </title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{% static 'css/newuser.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "page-header">
        <h1> Welcome to My Site </h1>
    </div>
    <style>
      .container {
           margin-left: 300px;
           margin-right: 300px;
      }
   </style>
   <div class = "container">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="signup" class="thumbnail">
                <img src="/static/img/signup.jpg" alt = "Sign Up as New User">
                </a>
                <h3> Sign Up </h3>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
               <a href="login" class="thumbnail">
               <img src="/static/img/login.jpg" alt = "Log In as Existing User">
               </a>
               <h3> Log In </h3>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are asking. When the user clicks on signup they will go to the signup view, and the same for login. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, once they're on signup view, i would want to gather the form data and if I edit the corresponding view, the page will not be displayed. How can I edit the index view so I can render both signup and login using an if-else?

Comment: So are you trying to get the information a user puts into fields and then do something with that data?  Or are you trying to get the users to redirect to a certain view from the index.html?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt, I want to redirect them to the appropriate view from index.html. But I have used hyperlinks and thumbnails since that is the design choice I made. If I had a button, I could use the on-click attribute...but how do I achieve the same in this case?

Comment: If all you want is to redirect on clicking a hyperlink you can use the code you already have just include a forward slash `<a href="/login" class="thumbnail">...</a>`

Comment: @MichaelPlatt, by adding a "/" in the href, does this mean I can now edit the views for signup and login to gather form data and do things with it? So I don't need to have the render call to those pages in the login and signup views?

Comment: Not sure what version of Django you are using but I would point you to this document here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/  It helped me a lot when spinning up on Django and it doesn't sound like you have a full grasp on how Django fully functions.  Essentially for every single view has an accompanying .html file and view method to go along with it.  Try giving that link a read and building a sample application and see how that works.  If you are still confused feel free to ask :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please avoid hard-coding urls in Django. You can use the power of reverse url matching here. Since you already have name assigned to your urls, you can have `container` in your `index.html` like this:

```
<div class = "container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="/static/img/signup.jpg" alt = "Sign Up as New User">
            </a>
            <h3> Sign Up </h3>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
           <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="thumbnail">
           <img src="/static/img/login.jpg" alt = "Log In as Existing User">
           </a>
           <h3> Log In </h3>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This would help in redirecting to corresponding urls using your `urls.py`.

Next, you need to create a `forms` to be displayed on `signup` and `login` page. Since you've imported `Customer` from models, I'm assuming that you want to create `signup` and `login` for them.

So you can put in your `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm
from django import forms

from .models import Customer

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Username", max_length=30,
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'username'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", max_length=30,
                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'name': 'password'}))


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

In `SignUpForm` you can also specify the fields you want from the user while registering by providing `fields` as a list of attributes of `Customer` model.

In your `login.html` you can provide a space for your `LoginForm` to render like:

```
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    <b>{{ field.label }}</b>:
    {{ field }}<br>
    {{ field.errors }}
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
</form>
```

Similarly your `signup.html` would also provide form like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'signup' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    <b>{{ field.label }}</b>:
    {{ field }}<br>
    {{ field.errors }}<br>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">
</form>
```

Finally edit your `login` and `signup` views to store the data like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

from .forms import LoginForm, SignUpForm

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse("Logged in", status=200)
        else:
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'login.html', context=context, status=401)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LoginForm(None)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'login.html', context=context)


def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'signup.html', context=context)
        return HttpResponse("Registered Successfully", status=200)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SignUpForm(None)
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'signup.html', context=context)
```

Note here that I've used login and logout functionality of `django.contrib.auth`. This may not be what you want for your application. But the idea is pretty much similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i follow what you are asking exactly, but if its just the directing the user in the  urls then you should use the url template tag with something like this

```
<a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="/static/img/signup.jpg" alt = "Sign Up as New User">
</a>

<a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="thumbnail">
    <img src="/static/img/login.jpg" alt = "Log In as Existing User">
</a>
```

because you named the urls in urls.py you can reference them by name in the url template tag and it will figure out the full url.

for example as you named this one login

```
url(r'^login$', views.login, name = 'login'),
```

using the following

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="thumbnail">click here</a>
```

will cause it to render with the url http://yoursite.com/login

if you are actually looking to record the clicks the user makes that is slightly more involved and you probably want to setup some model to persist the data and then catch the clicks in the views somehow